# Find DB column maximum length from backend when using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc, orm

I am using Hibernate (JPA packages as well at places) as ORM in my code base.
I have POJOs and their corresponding hbm files.

Now I am given with the POJO class name. I need to get the DB table name of that mapped POJO and maximum allowed length of each and every DB field of that table.

After some initial research I am under the impression that I probably need to use classes like `DatabaseMetaData`, `ResultSet`, `ResultSetMetaData`, etc, but however have no clue about them.I am also open to other approaches.

I need the cleanest approach to this and also that is better in terms of performance.
Please help.